# How should I do to install jquery?

Tags: jquery

When I try to install jquery from the site itself, it doesn't download any files. It just appears the code in a new tab. How should I do?

Comment: Did you use the download links at https://jquery.com/download/

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 0):

You can get a CDN version of the `.js` file located at [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/).

All you need to do is reference it in your HTML `<head>` tag like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```